# How can I test Exception with JUnit4

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-testing

Here's a simple function that convert a string to currency format.

```
fun String.toCurrency(): String{
    return try {
        DecimalFormat("###,###").format(this.replace(",","").toInt())
    } catch (E: NumberFormatException) {
        this
    }
}
```

And I want to test this method. So, I did

```
    @Test(expected = NumberFormatException::class)
    @Throws(NumberFormatException::class)
    fun convertCurrency_returnAmericanFormat() {
        val currentList = listOf("0", "1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000", "100000", "1000000", "100000000")
        val expectedList = listOf("0", "1", "10", "100", "1,000", "10,000", "100,000", "1,000,000", "100,000,000")

        currentList.forEachWithIndex { i, s ->
            assertEquals(expectedList[i], s.toCurrency())
        }
        val exceptionList = listOf("!", "@")
        exceptionList.forEach {
            try {
                it.toCurrency()
            }catch (e: NumberFormatException){
                assertEquals(NumberFormatException::class, e)
            }
        }
    }
```

It didn't work and shows failure.

How can I pass the test case? I don't need to check the message but just ExceptionClass.

Answer (score 0):

In `toCurrency` extension function, you are catching the number format exception and returning the original string. You should rethrow the exception or not to catch it at all.

```kotlin
// ...
catch(e: NumberFormatException) {
    // log the exception or ...
    throw e 
}
```

Here, let's test only invalid scenario for `toCurrency` method. It would be easy to determine which test scenario failing or successing.

```kotlin
@Test
fun convertCurrency_invalidNumbers_throwsException() {
    val invalidCurrencies = listOf("!", "@")
    // check also for big numbers -> 999999999999

    assertThrows<NumberFormatException> {
        invalidCurrencies.forEach {
        it.toCurrency()
    }
  }
}

@Test
@Throws(NumberFormatException::class)
fun convertCurrency_returnAmericanFormat() {
    // test for successful toCurrency conversion
}
```